# Flutter expansionTile title padding

Tags: flutter, dart, padding

How we can remove space between leading and title in Flutter ExpansionTile?
[image]

Comment: tried wrapping `leading` with `SizedBox` / `ConstrainedBox`?

Comment: Yes. not worked.

Comment: seems you cannot make it smaller than [_minLeadingWidth](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1312)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try below snipppet

```
ExpansionTile(title: Row(children: [
  // Icon View,
  // SizedBox of desired width,
  // Text View
  ]),
  children:  ... ,)
```

If you want to remove padding out side your view
Set ExpantionTile tile padding to zero

```
ExpansionTile(tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
     title: Row(children: [
  // Icon View,
  // SizedBox of desired width,
  // Text View
  ]),
  children:  ... ,)
```

Comment: TilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero is a working solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `title` with `Alignment` like below

```
title: Align(
      child: Text(
          "Your text over here"
      ),
      //You may change value from -1.5 to anything which works better for you
      alignment: Alignment(-1.5, 0),
    ),
    dense: true,
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListTile(

  title: Row(

  children: <Widget>[

   Icon(Icons.android),

       Text("Title")
],),)
```